# Prime number in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, primes

I was trying to write a simple prime number program in Java 8. Below is the program. I wanted to reduce the code in `isPrime()` as well. Is there something that filters the elements from `2` to `n/2`, and then apply filter for `n%i == 0` which would make `isPrime` irrelevant?

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Stream1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20);
        // Prime number 
        System.out.println(numbers.stream()
                             .filter(Stream1::isPrime)
                             .collect(toList()));
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: While it is nice to use Java 8 streams, if you want to compute primes fast in Java, you would do better to use conventional loops ... and pick a good algorithm.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) can be used to generate integer stream

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    return !IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number/2).anyMatch(i -> number%i == 0); 
}
```

or

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number/2).noneMatch(i -> number%i == 0);
}
```

Comment: IntStream::noneMatch could also be used instead: return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number/2).noneMatch(i -> number%i == 0);

Comment: Instead of doing it in the isPrime method can we do it in the main stream itself?

Comment: @srborlongan Thanks. Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: You only need to check from 2 to sqrt(number)

Comment: As stated before, you only need to go `sqrt(number)`. But more importantly, the implementation itself is wrong. The very first test number in the question to test is one. This code recognizes number one as a prime number! As the range will be empty, so none will match. But the same will happen with number zero as it is also recognized by this code as prime, and all the negative numbers as well.

Answer (score 10):

Your `isPrime()` is inefficient.  First, you do not need to divide by any even numbers greater than 2, since an initial division by 2 will catch all even non-primes.  Second, you terminate your loop at `number / 2` instead of the more efficient `sqrt(number)`.

You could rewrite your method something like this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {

    // Low numbers
    if (number < 2) {
      return false;
    }

    // Even numbers
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return number == 2;
    }

    // Odd numbers
    int limit = (int)(0.1 + Math.sqrt(number));
    for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The Sieve of Eratosthenes would be more efficient still, but that might be overkill for a relatively small problem.

Comment: OP is not rooting for optimization. He wants only java8 solution to minimize the code. Also `i*i <= number` would be slightly more optimal than `i <= sqrt(number)`

Comment: @ShashwatKumar OP might not even know there is a better way... plus one.

Comment: @Shaswat It might be more optimal for checking small numbers.  For checking large numbers, either prime or with only large prime factors, then pre-calculating the square root once only is better.  It depends on the data the method is fed.

Comment: Number one is not a prime, however this implementation retrns `true`. Similarly for negative odd numbers it returns `true` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Code amended.

Comment: Good answer! I am curious to know why you have added 0.1. [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) doesn't mention adding 0.1.

Comment: @Arvind. It is for cases where you are testing a square number, and the decimal square root calculation is just a little off, something like giving "sqrt(49) = 6.999982543" which gets truncated down to 6 instead of the correct 7. Adding 0.1 will make sure it is truncated to the correct value. HTH.

Answer (score 5):

You can use algorithm [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) like this

```
public static IntStream primes(int max) {
    IntStream primes = IntStream.range(2, max);
    IntFunction<IntPredicate> sieve = n -> i -> i == n || i % n != 0;
    primes = primes.filter(sieve.apply(2));
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= max; i += 2)
        primes = primes.filter(sieve.apply(i));
    return primes;
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(primes(100).count());    // -> 25
System.out.println(primes(1000).count());   // -> 168
System.out.println(primes(10000).count());  // -> 1229
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggest by @rossum you can use the famous [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for this and it will compute the primes pretty fast.

```
 private static BitSet primes(int limit) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(limit);
    bitSet.set(0, false);
    bitSet.set(1, false);
    bitSet.set(2, limit, true);

    for (int i = 2; i * i < limit; ++i) {

        if (bitSet.get(i)) {
            int j = i;
            int x = 2;
            while (j < limit) {
                j = i * x;
                bitSet.set(j, false);
                ++x;
            }
        }

    }

    return bitSet;
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = i * i; j < limit; j += i) { bitSet.set(j, false); }` will probably save a lot of cycles. Your `x` should start at `i` because for the values from `2*i` to `i*(i-1)`, were already set to false in the previous iterations. There are less useless computations, and multiplication is replaced by addition, which is usually easier for the CPU.

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##VZAxb4MwEIX3/IoboaFWUnWjWbp16MQYZXDJBR0FQ@yDtqry2@lhm4gimZN933v37FqP@rE@f04TtX1nGWo5UANTo16JC@R8UzbaOXjXZOB3A9APHw2V4FizlLGjM7TSSwq2ZKrjCbStXOpRgFFbaKglhgO8GcYKreq1dSibZAaPu1Oa31FHOKKgvaUWi3mTeHVEih/H2KpuYCWE4cYkXqEcW9RtkqqyG8Q49fxNVkwZrrK2FXUItk66jDf4FSX/xsdZcvqUBXEGbAeM7UtnwfuSWAjhrlKf87m@BDz3rWBj8HseIGMSgi3s0yggeABaQq1M61l5zaXezWrYHtbsOmGdwUU3bskWXmP5W@TBmkCHl7pN07TfLd8f) is an  optimized version to reduce cycle usage.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire oh, that is a great point. I will leave the code as is and let anyone else to defer to your excellent comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stream as this test below:

```
@Test
public void generatePrimeNumberListByStream(){
    List<Integer> primeNumbers =
            IntStream
                    .range(2,30)
                    .filter(number -> IntStream.range(2,number)
                            .noneMatch(divider -> number % divider == 0))
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertThat(primeNumbers, contains(2,3,5,7,11,13, 17,19, 23, 29));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    return i % 2 != 0 && IntStream.iterate(
            3, n -> n <= (int)(Math.sqrt(i)), n -> n + 2)
            .noneMatch(k->i%k==0);
}
```

iterate takes 3 parameters, similar to a for loop, base is the start, the second is the stop condition, third is the increment rule.
1 and 2 are prime already so we start at 3 and we stop before reaching the square root of the number. The idea is that suppose n is a positive integer  n=pq, where p and q are prime numbers. Assume p greater than square root of n and greater than square root of n. Multiplying these inequalities we have p*q > sqrt n * sqrt n, which implies pq > n. This is a contradiction to our hypothesis n=pq. Hence we can conclude that either p less or equal sqrt n or q less than equal sqrt n.

> n -> n <= (int)(Math.sqrt(i))

finally we do not need to check even numbers as long as it is not divisible by 2 so we only try every second number.

> (n -> n+2)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: While the code may answer the question, it is always best to provide explanation. Please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: Thanks guys added some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 100).filter(i -> isPrime(i)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);

}

static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    return number > 1 && IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number/2).noneMatch(i -> number % i == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired using predicate as well.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PrimeUsingStream {

     public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
            IntPredicate isDivisible = index -> i % index == 0;
            return i > 1 && IntStream.range(2, i).noneMatch(isDivisible);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

        //System.out.println(printPrime(200));

         List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20,23);
            // Prime number 
        System.out.println(numbers.stream()
                                 .filter(PrimeUsingStream::isPrime)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList()));
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java8+ solution**

```
public static boolean isPrime(long number) {
    return number>1 && LongStream.rangeClosed(2, number / 2).noneMatch(i -> number % i == 0);
}
```

***need to exclude 1!!***

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Answer (score 0):

I am coming late to the game, but I am sharing my solution because there is a surprising number of incorrect implementations shared and the following code has better performance than the other `boolean isPrime(int candidate)` solutions.

The solution in the original post, the accepted answer, and many more answers are incorrect because they identify negative numbers, zero, and one as prime numbers, which they are not. See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers.

The solution is faster than other `boolean isPrime(int candidate)` solutions due to:

- It is sufficient to do the check up to `Math.sqrt(candidate)`.
- The original post likes to use Java 8's Stream API. However, most people want prime calculations to be fast, which is more important than using the Stream API what would bring huge overhead.
- It uses the fact that all primes (except 2 and 3) have to be at `6k±1`. Therefore, it skips testing numbers that are divisible by 2 or 3. It will only test the groups of (5, 7), (11, 13) and so on.

```
static boolean isPrime(int candidate) {
    if (candidate < 4) {
        return candidate > 1;
    }
    if (candidate % 2 == 0 || candidate % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 5; i <= Math.sqrt(candidate); i += 6) {
        if (candidate % i == 0 || candidate % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```